# How can I join same rows together of the same pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, row

on a data frame that contains columns for all the countries in the world. The countries are repeated multiple times in each row, and the other columns contain values like the total cases of COVID-19. I can combine the countries and simultaneously add the values of the total cases column, related to that particular country.

The data set can be observed here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kunwarakash/covid-cases-and-vaccination-data.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the .groupby() method?

```
df.groupby('country').sum()
```

should group the country column together and sum all the other columns by country